# Using multiple http proxies in groovy

Tags: http, groovy

I need to use multiple http proxies in parallel in a groovy script. E.g.

```
url1 = 'https://boston.myorg.com' 
proxy1 = 10.0.0.3:8000
url2 = 'https://newyork.myorg.com'
proxy2 = 10.0.0.5:8001
```

I have found examples like the one below, but wouldn't that set the proxy for every connection in the script? Is there a way to do this so that each connection uses it's own proxy?

```
System.properties.putAll( ["http.proxyHost":"proxy-host", "http.proxyPort":"proxy-port"] )  
    def url = 'http://www.google.com/images/logo.gif'  
    def file = new FileOutputStream(address.tokenize("/")[-1])  
    def out = new BufferedOutputStream(file)  
    out << new URL(address).openStream()  
    out.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html

**Proxy class** section

```
SocketAddress proxy1Addr = new InetSocketAddress("10.0.0.3", 8000)
Proxy proxy1 = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, proxy1Addr)

URL url1 = new URL("https://boston.myorg.com/")
URLConnection conn1 = url1.openConnection(proxy1)
```